# Magento transactionnal emails order.getBillingAddress()

Tags: email, magento, transactional

I'm searching the block that is called when I used the var {{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}} in order_new.html email template.

I need to remove some information displayed by this block.

Thank for your precious help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formatting of the address is done in the class `Mage_Customer_Block_Address_Renderer_Default`.

The best way to remove some data from the rendered address is by adjusting the address templates. In order to do that let me explain how Magento chooses an address template.

1) In a nutshell, first Magento tries to load a format template from the table `directory_country_format` for the specified type (`html`, `pdf`, `oneline`, `text`). This gives Magento the capability to have country specific address templates.

If it doesn't find one, it will use the format template from the configuration, using the xpath `customer/address_templates/$type`.
The defaults can be found in the *Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml* file.
They can be overridden using the system configuration interface found under *System > Config > Customer Configuration > Address Templates* on a store level.

Comment: Ok. So I need to override the Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml file.
Thanks for your help

Comment: If you would be so nice to accept the answer to your question I would appreciate it (gives stack overflow reputation).