# Magento address template for invoice pdf

Tags: php, pdf, magento-1.7

I have a question about the Magento invoice address layout. This is for my country in the wrong order.

In the backend -> system -> configuration -> clients -> client configuration there is an option for the address layout. This should also work in the invoice pdf.

I changed it to this:

```
    {{depend company}}{{var company}}|{{/depend}}
    {{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}|
    {{if street1}}{{var street1}}{{/if}}
    {{depend street2}}{{var street2}}|{{/depend}}
    {{depend street3}}{{var street3}}|{{/depend}}
    {{depend street4}}{{var street4}}|{{/depend}}
    {{if city}}{{var city}},|{{/if}}
    {{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}|
    {{var country}}|
    {{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}|
    {{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}|
    {{depend vat_id}}<br/>VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}|
```

But the company name is still placed after the names.

The version of Magento is 1.7.0.2

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Ps. I've cleared the cache :)

Comment: Anybody has any tips where to look? I've also found a xml with the same configuration, modifying this one also didn't work. What can I do to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer was allready on stackoverflow.

[Magento transactionnal emails order.getBillingAddress()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194663/magento-transactionnal-emails-order-getbillingaddress)

The address templates are stored in the database table directory_country_format